# Introspector getBeanInfo on bean with generic implemented method

Tags: java, generics, interface, overriding, javabeans

Good day everyone. I'm using Vaadin and got a problem with BeanItemContainer. I have a generic interface and a bean implementing that interface

```
package ru.package.testpackage;

public class SomeTest {
    interface SomeHavingId<T> {
        T getId();
        void setId(T id);
    }

    class TestBean implements SomeHavingId<Integer> {
        public TestBean(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Override
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        @Override
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private Integer id;
    }
}
```

The problem is that Vaadin inside `BeanItemContainer` uses `Introspector.getBeanInfo(TestBean.class)` to parse setters and getters to create property map. But instead of resolving a `Integer getId()` I get `java.lang.Object getId()`. As far as I see, Introspector is not able to understand the interface being implemented in `SomeHavingId<Integer>` way.

So that's my question - what should I do to get correct method signature if:

1. I can't change source code of that bean
2. I can't change source code of Vaadin

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Because you can change the sourcecode of the BeanInspector. I recommend to use JRE7. There exist two pairs of get/set, one for Integer and one for Object, causes by the generic interface(you never seethe sec one in java but in bytecode and reflection). With the JRE7 the problem should be solved due to better decision which get/set-pair to use.

Comment: I'm using JRE1.5 due to target platform restrictions. I wish I could hop on JRE7.